# Independent Random Variables Subtracted by Another Independent Random Variable

Tags: probability, independence

Suppose $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are independent random variables. Is it true that $X-Z$ and $Y-Z$ are independent?

I know that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then for every constant $c\in\mathbb{R}$, $X-c$ and $Y-c$ are independent. This can be easily proved by
$$
\mathbb{P}(X-c\le x,\,Y-c\le y)=\mathbb{P}(X\le x+c,\,Y\le y+c)=\mathbb{P}(X\le x+c)\mathbb{P}(Y\le y+c)=\mathbb{P}(X-c\le x)\mathbb{P}(Y-c\le y).
$$

I tried to modify this proof for the case when $Z$ is discrete by using conditional probability. Suppose $Z$ takes value in $\{0,1,2,...\}$. Then
$$
\mathbb{P}(X-Z\le x,\,Y-Z\le y)
=
\sum_{z=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X-Z\le x,\,Y-Z\le y\mid Z=z)\mathbb{P}(Z=z)
=
\sum_{z=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X-z\le x,\,Y-z\le y)\mathbb{P}(Z=z)
=
\sum_{z=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X-z\le x)\mathbb{P}(Y-z\le y)\mathbb{P}(Z=z)
$$
but I do not know how to proceed.

---

**Update:** The answer is no. Following the hint provided by JKL, I obtained the following counterexample. Suppose
$$
\mathbb{P}(X=1)=1,\quad\mathbb{P}(Y=-1)=1,\quad\mathbb{P}(Z=1)=\mathbb{P}(Z=-1)=1/2.
$$
Then $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are independent. Let $X'=X-Z$ and $Y'=Y-Z$. Then
$$
\mathbb{P}(X'=0)=\mathbb{P}(X'=2)=\frac{1}{2},
\quad
\mathbb{P}(Y'=0)=\mathbb{P}(Y'=-2)=\frac{1}{2}.
$$
However, $\mathbb{P}(X'=0,\,Y'=0)=\mathbb{P}(X=Y=Z)=0\neq\mathbb{P}(X'=0)\mathbb{P}(Y'=0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about some (counter)examples where information given by $X - Z$ might tell you what the value of $Y - Z$ might be. For example, what happens if $X$ and $Y$ are "small", but $Z$ is "large"? Then if you know that $X - Z$ has a large negative value, what might you be able to say about the value of $Y - Z$?

To be more concrete, you can even think of the most trivial example. Let $X = a$ and $Y = b$ almost surely for some constants $a \ne b \in \mathbb{R}$. What happens in this case?